# Azure Multifactor Authentication with Meraki Security Appliance Client VPN

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-authentication

We have a Meraki MX65w security appliance that we are attempting to configure 2-Factor authentication for Client VPN using Azure Multifactor Authentication Server.  The Azure MFA server is installed on a Windows 2012 Server that is functioning as a domain controller.  So far we have got the Meraki Client VPN to communicate with the Azure MFA Server via RADIUS and authenticate using Azure MFA using the Windows Domain, but as soon as a user authenticates the VPN fails on the client machine.  When this fails, we get an Event Viewer error 691 on the client machine.

Has anyone been able to get this to work or have any insight?

Below are our logs for the Meraki and Azure MFA Server.

**MFA Server Log:**

Apr 19 12:55:04 "servername" pfsvc: 0|pfAuth|e4a442c5-3bce-4569-b815-f74998d9dc3d|#authType=radius

Apr 19 12:55:04 "servername" pfsvc: 0|pfAuth|e4a442c5-3bce-4569-b815-f74998d9dc3d|#applicationName= "App Name"

Apr 19 12:55:04 "servername" pfsvc: 0|pfAuth|e4a442c5-3bce-4569-b815-f74998d9dc3d|#username="username"

Apr 19 12:55:04 "servername" pfsvc: 0|pfAuth|e4a442c5-3bce-4569-b815-f74998d9dc3d|#countryCode='1'

Apr 19 12:55:04 "servername" pfsvc: 0|pfAuth|e4a442c5-3bce-4569-b815-f74998d9dc3d|#phoneNumber="phonenumber"

Apr 19 12:55:04 "servername" pfsvc: 0|pfAuth|e4a442c5-3bce-4569-b815-f74998d9dc3d|#phoneExtension=''

Apr 19 12:55:04 "servername" pfsvc: 0|pfAuth|e4a442c5-3bce-4569-b815-f74998d9dc3d|#authRequestMode=sms

Apr 19 12:55:04 "servername" pfsvc: 0|pfAuth|e4a442c5-3bce-4569-b815-f74998d9dc3d|#Requesting response from popConn.

Apr 19 12:55:13 "servername" pfsvc: 0|pfAuth|e4a442c5-3bce-4569-b815-f74998d9dc3d|#Got Response.

Apr 19 12:55:13 "servername" pfsvc: 0|pfAuth|e4a442c5-3bce-4569-b815-f74998d9dc3d|#authenticated = true

Apr 19 12:55:13 "servername" pfsvc: i|pfsvc|e4a442c5-3bce-4569-b815-f74998d9dc3d|#Pfauth succeeded for user "username".  Call status: SUCCESS_SMS_AUTHENTICATED - "SMS Authenticated".

Apr 19 12:55:13 "servername"pfsvc: Pfauth succeeded for user "username".  Call status: SUCCESS_SMS_AUTHENTICATED - "SMS Authenticated".

**Meraki Log:**

Apr 19 12:59:22   1492621123.038484109  events Site-to-site VPN: invalid DH group 20.

Apr 19 12:59:22   1492621123.044228839  events Site-to-site VPN: invalid DH group 19.

Apr 19 12:59:22   1492621123.078883895  events Site-to-site VPN: ISAKMP-SA established XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[4500]-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[4500] spi:3c0b8c455e8bce17:ab2e64f2e82cc0f6

Apr 19 12:59:22   1492621123.096275876  events Site-to-site VPN: not matched

Apr 19 12:59:22   1492621123.106365076  events Site-to-site VPN: IPsec-SA established: ESP/Transport XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[4500]->XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[4500] spi=24782156(0x17a254c)

Apr 19 12:59:22   1492621123.112679864  events Site-to-site VPN: IPsec-SA established: ESP/Transport XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[4500]->XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[4500] spi=2850023456(0xa9dfe820)

Apr 19 12:59:25   1492621125.847448434  urls src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:49478 dst=134.170.165.75:443 mac=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx request: UNKNOWN https://pfd.phonefactor.net/...

Apr 19 12:59:42   1492621143.417618358  events Site-to-site VPN: no configuration found for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.

Apr 19 12:59:42   1492621143.424528373  events Site-to-site VPN: failed to begin ipsec sa negotication.